# Get attribute text field with html

Tags: product, attributes, product-page

I created an text field attribute and allowed HTML on frontend and also tried enabling WYSIWYG.

I load the attribute on productpage with this line:

```
<?php if($_product->getData('standaard_meegeleverd')) : ?>
<h2 class="productbox-titles-reviews">Standaard meegeleverd</h2>
<div><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('standaard_meegeleverd')); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But on frontend the data is loaded without HTML.
I see text on the product page like this:

```
<p>AC-adapter</p> <p>4 cell Li-ion-accu</p>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try removing the `htmlEscape`

So:

```
 <div><?php echo $_product->getData('standaard_meegeleverd'); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Its Working for me. please try this.

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct();?>
<?php echo $_product->getData('system_requirement'); ?>
```

> here system_requirement is attribute code. please replace with your attribute code.